# Paso de valores entre paginas razor, asp.net Core 2.2

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, cshtml

estoy haciendo una pagina con asp.net 2.2 y c#. tengo 3 paginas Razor.
Una con un formulario y otras dos, una con un buscador de personas y otra con un buscador de actividades.
Mediante un botón desde el formulario redirecciono a las otras dos. 
Lo que no soy capaz es pasar los valores(mediante un boton de seleccion) nombre y edad de la pagina de personal y lo mismo con la actividad y el numero de horas a la semana. 
Tanto la de personal como de la de actividades son clases sencillas que traen los datos de base de datos sql(para esto no tengo problemas).
he intentado pasar el ID con:

```
 <a asp-route-id="@item.Id"  asp-page="Formulario" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Selecionar</a>
```

pero cuando viene el de personal se borra el de actividades y viceversa.

podeis echarme una mano? o decirme por donde puedo tirar? soy nuevo en esto y tengo pocos recursos.
muchas gracias.
un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Para recibir mas de un dato analicemos

[Anchor Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Veras que si usas el `asp-route-{value}` solo podrias enviar un unico dato, aunque si puede redefinir el nombre como ser `asp-route-edad`, pero entiendo sera solo uno para que arme una url como ser

```
/Controller/Action/{edad}
```

Ahora si tienes algo como esto

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ActionName(int edad, string nombre)
{ 
   //codigo
}
```

deberias evluar usar `asp-all-route-data` al cual le asignas un dictionary

```
@{
   var parms = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
               { "nombre", item.Nombre },
               { "edad", item.Edad }
            };
 }

 <a asp-all-route-data="parms"  asp-page="Formulario" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Selecionar</a>
```

asi la url se arma pasando los datos

```
 /Controller/action?nombre=Nombre&edad=Edad
```

Model Binding mapeara los nombres de a url con los parametros del action

Comment: gracias por tu comentario. Al incluir el var parms me da error, me pide ; } error en el =... etc.
tambien decirte, si no me equivoco, en las paginas razor no se usan controladores.

Comment: estas seguro que no olvidaste cerrar ninguna llave ? si usas asp.net mvc los template aplica Razor, pero deben invocar funcionalidad en el servidor, eso se implementa en un controller con sus action